# How to delete records from database table excluding records from another SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a search log table, I keep search logs. Table structure is like searchstring, date, number of results of each search string as results and some other info. I have the following SQL that I get records I need. A keyword could be searched several times so latest date is important. I use following SQL to get records I need. It's working fine.

```
SELECT id, searchstring, max(logdate) as logdate 
FROM log_search 
WHERE locale = 'en' AND results > 0 
GROUP BY searchstring 
ORDER BY logdate DESC
```

My problem is there are millions of records and I need to clean it up. I just want to keep records that matches sql above.

I tried to use `NOT IN` over `id` field but since sorting by logdate is important didn't let me.

`DELETE FROM log_search WHERE id NOT IN (...MYQUERY...)` but it gives `Operand should contain 1 column(s)` error

Another important field is `locale` . While deleting records for `en` I need to keep other locales even though they don't match my SQL above.

Is there a way to delete records and keep the ones I need.

**EDIT**

Table structure
Id - Auto increment
searchstring
results - containt number of results for that searchstring
logdate - date and time that search is made

`results` and `logdate` both are important to get latest query that return result.

**SOLUTION / WORKAROUND**

@Sunny's answer technically works, but for big tables like some millions of records, it's performance is awful. Insted, I did a workaround by creating another table and inserting records I need into there. Here is my SQL

```
INSERT INTO log_search_simple
SELECT id, searchstring, max(logdate) as logdate, locale
FROM log_search 
WHERE locale = 'en' AND results > 0 
GROUP BY searchstring 
ORDER BY logdate DESC
```

Comment: @echo_Me I tried DELETE FROM log_search WHERE id NOT IN (...MYQUERY...) but it gives `Operand should contain 1 column(s)` error

Answer (score 0):

You may try this...

```
Delete from log_search where NOT EXISTS (SELECT id, searchstring, max(logdate) as logdate 
FROM log_search 
WHERE locale = 'en' AND results > 0 
GROUP BY searchstring 
ORDER BY logdate DESC)
```

Comment: First doesnt work. Second one, using NOT EXISTS doesn't let you work on the same table while searching and deleting. I duplicated it and used two tables but affected rows are zero.

Answer (score 0):

Your try is right you just need to select one column of id instead of multiple columns.

Try that.

```
            DELETE FROM log_search FROM log_search WHERE id Not in (SELECT id FROM log_search WHERE locale = 'en' AND results > 0 GROUP BY searchstring )
```

Comment: logdate is important. need to keep latest record.

Comment: I guess you dont need logdate in the delete. You need the id row which is specified by your where clause. Logdate you just selecting it.

Comment: that's the problem `Not In` does not let you use more than one column in `SELECT` statement

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
DELETE FROM log_search where id NOT IN(
SELECT id FROM (
SELECT id, searchstring, max(logdate) as logdate 
FROM log_search 
WHERE locale = 'en' AND results > 0 
GROUP BY searchstring 
ORDER BY logdate DESC
) AS a);
```

> **Operand should contain 1 column(s)**

It looks for 1 column to match data for a column and for here it is getting three columns in result set by SELECT statement. So the quick solution is to slice a column from the result set and match the column. it will do the trick :)

Comment: Technically it works, but practically, I let it run like 5 minutes and deleted only around 30,000 records out of some hundreds of thousands. Not a good idea for big tables. If noone posts a better answer I'll accept it.